# Testing AsyncListDiffer, how can I get notified after the background comparing operation finished?

Tags: unit-testing, android-asynclistdiffer

I want to unit test the RecyclerView Adapter, which has AsyncListDiffer implemented. But I couldn't find a way how can I get notified after calling differ.submitList(list), when the background operation finishes the checking on the list. Is there any way to do this? Or do the runnable operation asynchronously?